# Checagem de modelo de aparelho ao publicar na play store

Tags: android, google-play

Olá,

Quero publicar um aplicativo na play store, porem gostaria que ficasse disponível apenas para modelos que tem tela edge (s6 edge,s7 edge, s8, s8+, etc) e para outros modelos ficasse mostrando como a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(imagem apenas para demonstrar)

Como que é feito essa checagem?

É via código?

É pela própria playstore?

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Sim, é na Play Store. Basta acessar `Gerenciamento da Versão` > `Catálogo de Dispositivos`

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455

Comment: Obrigado Valdeir

Comment: Pela própria PlayStore você consegue controlar isso.